# Why is int.MinValue.GetHashCode() == int.MaxValue.GetHashCode() is false, but Int64.MinValue.GetHashCode() == Int64.MaxValue.GetHashCode() is true?

Tags: c#, .net, integer, hashcode

Why is `int.MinValue.GetHashCode() == int.MaxValue.GetHashCode()` is false, but `Int64.MinValue.GetHashCode() == Int64.MaxValue.GetHashCode()` is true?

For both 32-bit integer and 64-bit integer, `MinValue != MaxValue` but for the 64 bit version, the HashCode is the same (`-2147483648`)?

Comment: Yes, hash codes can have collisions - that's how they can be smaller than what they are hashing. Comparing hash codes for different keys is meaningless.

Comment: well for starters: `GetHashCode` returns an `Int32` - so there's bound to be many collisions between _all_ possible `Int64`-values. that specifically those two collide might be coincidence, or due to their internal representation and the hash-implementation.

Comment: Can you better explain your use case for comparing these? Are you trying to store the numbers in a dictionary, for example?

Comment: The only rule is that two values which compare equal (as with `Equals`) must have the same hash code. The opposite isn't true: two different values can have the same hash code.